# How to pull status response codes from the backend and use it in the frontend?

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I am trying to send status response codes from the backend which is in Node.js to my frontend which is in Angular in order to display an error message "Email already exists".

// Frontend

```
add.user.component.ts

 if (this.AddUserForm.valid) {
      this.AuthService.register(this.AddUserForm.value)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(
        data => {
            this.router.navigate(['dashboard/user']);
          this.snackbar.open('User has been Added', 'Close', {
            duration: 3000,
          });
        },
        error => {
          this.loading = false;
          this.snackbar.open('Unsuccessful', 'Close', {
            duration: 3000,
          });
        },
      );
    }
```

authentication.service.ts

```
register(user: User) {
    // const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')).token });
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.environment.userUrl}/auth/register`, user);
  }
```

// Backend

authentication.js

```
exports.register = function (req, res, next) {

    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = generator.generate({
        length: 10,
        numbers:true,
        uppercase:true,
        symbols: true
    });


    if (!email) {
        return res.status(422).send({
            error: 'You must enter an email address'
        });
    }

    User.findOne({
        email: email
    }, function (err, existingUser) {

        if (err) {

            return next(err);
        }

        if (existingUser) {
            return res.status(422).send({
                error: 'That email address is already in use'
            });
        }

        var user = new User({
            email: email,
             password: password,

        });

        user.save(function (err, user, done) {

            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }

            var userInfo = setUserInfo(user);

            res.status(201).json({
                message: 'Please Check you Email Address',
                 token: 'JWT ' + generateToken(userInfo),
                user: userInfo
            });
```

The response code needs to be sent from the backend to my frontend. Here, in this case, response status code 422 needs to be sent to my frontend

Answer (score 0):

In the response object you can add the statuCode value.

```
if (existingUser) {
            return res.status(422).send({
                error: 'That email address is already in use',
                statusCode: 422
            });
        }
```

Comment: How will I pull this statusCode in my frontend?

Comment: @NileshMaharjan Tried using response.status/error.status?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz: I'm not sure where to place response.status in this function. Could you show me how it's done?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just read the status directly on the `HttpResponse` without including it in the response json:

```
this.AuthService.register(this.AddUserForm.value)
  .pipe(first())
  .subscribe(data => console.log(data.status));
```

You might have to add this too to the http call:

```
{observe: 'response'}
```

So it becomes like this:

```
this.http.post<any>(`${this.environment.userUrl}/auth/register`, user, {observe: 'response'});
```